# How to play a running video from 1sec - 20sec in Blend/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video, blend

To play a video for just **20sec out of the whole video** in Blend/WPF using C# language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [C# Corner article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/VideoWPF04082007164613PM/VideoWPF.aspx) explains how to do it, including an example app.

You need something like this in your XAML (from the article):

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoControl" Width="200" Height ="400"
              Source="C:\TestV.MPG" >    
</MediaElement>
```